# Java Jersey RESTFUL API HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type with postman

Tags: java, rest, jersey, postman

I am trying to PUT data onto a MySQL database. I have written a RESTful web service and created a PUT function that takes JSON and adds the data to the MySQL database. When I try to use the PUT command through Postman I keep getting "HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type". I have made sure my headers in Postman are set up correctly and that my PUT function accepts JSON. Does anyone have any ideas as to while this isn't working? Thanks!

Java Code:

```
@PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response insertOccupation(Occupation occupation) {
        try{
            Occupation newOccupation = Occupation.insertOccupation(conn, occupation.getCompanyName(), occupation.getJobTitle(), occupation.getEmploymentType(), occupation.getMonthlySalary(), occupation.getIndustry());
            if(newOccupation!=null) {
                Gson json = new Gson();
                return Response.ok(json.toJson(newOccupation), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            }else {
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }
```

Postman:
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzBl4.png)

Comment: Have you added a [JSON provider](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) (assuming you're using Jersey 2.x) to your app?

Comment: I have not. After adding MOXY it fixed my problem thank you so much!